# Not able to install J2OBJC using terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, j2objc

I have download the J2OBJC version and while running the command on terminal
A:j2objc-master $ make dist

I am getting below error

building j2objc jar
javac: invalid source release: 1.8
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options
make[1]: *** [/Users/Downloads/j2objc-master/translator/build_result/j2objc.jar] Error 2
make: *** [translator] Error 2

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

That's a javac error, stating that the version of javac on your system (which is part of the JDK you have installed) does not support the [j2objc project's Java 8 minimum version](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/#requirements). Upgrade your system to [JDK 8 from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to support this minimum.

Comment: Hi i have been able to update . Now i am getting this error can you please suggest

src/main/java/com/google/devtools/j2objc/javac/JavadocConverter.java:155: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^

              ^
Note: src/main/java/com/google/devtools/j2objc/jdt/AbstractTypeBinding.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
100 errors
make[1]: *** [/Users/Documents/J2OBJC/translator/build_result/j2objc.jar] Error 1
make: *** [translator] Error 2